# Reading tab separated file into a defaultdict - Python

Tags: python, csv, data-structures, defaultdict

I have a data file that is formatted like `id<tab>data` per line, where there can be more than 1 data value for each `id` and vice-versa e.g. :

```
12314\tgerv 15253
43633\tsyujtyy 1243322
12314\tsgsd 134623
58667\tsgsd 134623
```

And I've came up with a function to read the data file into a `defaultdict`, where the default option is to use the `id` as key and sometimes using the data as `key` is useful too.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def readData(datafile, option="id"):
  data = defaultdict(list)
  reader = open(datafile)
  for l in reader:
    if option == "id":
      k, v = l.split("\t")
    else:
      v, k = l.split("\t")
    data[k].append(v)
  return data
```

The desired output is the `defaultdict` where keys and values are `id` and `data` or vice versa. Other than reading the data with the function above.

**Is there a better way to get the same `defaultdict` output?** The number of lines in the datafile ranges from 1000 - 100,000, in some cases up to 1 million.

**Other than reading the datafile into a `defaultdict`, is there other native data structure that is more appropriate?** The use of the data is just so that i can query the `dictionar` output with the `id` or the `data` key.

Comment: The only improvement that I can see is to pass the `delimiter='\t'` option to `csv.reader` and avoid calling `l.split("\t")`. In your case `reader` is completely useless and you could as well use a plain `open`. By the way, since your question is about working code it's better suited for [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: is there a difference in performance in using multiple `str.split()` and `csv.reader()`?

Comment: I have no idea, you should time it, even though I think that the difference wont be noticeable since the time is almost all taken by the I/O operations. Using `reader` *and* splitting the strings manually is certainly slower, since `csv.reader` adds some overhead for doing absolutely nothing. Either you use a plain file and split the lines manually, or let `reader` do all the work. (I did a fast benchmark and it seems that using `csv.reader` with `delimiter="\t"` is a bit faster).